# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2410).

Answer (score 26):

[image: Apply for Wolfram Summer School!]

Comment: Dear friends, **education** in [Wolfram Summer School](https://education.wolfram.com/summer/school/) is **free**, the cost is only travel and campus-living charged by Bentley University. Wolfram builds real-fun skill-building career-boosting academic program for 3 weeks in Boston and brings almost 100 top students and professors from around the world. Networking is amazing. **You can be a part** of it. Please **vote** this ad up, **apply** for the program and **spread the word** encouraging your friends and colleagues. Feel free to ask me any questions. Thank you & cheers!

Answer (score 25):

[image: Wolfram Developers Twitch]

Comment: "ET" is so U.S.-centric ... I think many readers won't even know what it means. Would it be possible to write this in a way that's friendlier to an international audience?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for pointing that out. I will ask and replace if a better image will be available.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov also wtf is ET? As an American I'm much more used to EST or EDT or even just Eastern.

Comment: Agreed - UTC/GMT would be much nicer.

Comment: Guys I will pass this internally :D I hope they can update.

Comment: @b3m2a1 The Twitch series goes past the change from EDT to EST, so neither of them is generically correct.  That also poses problems for giving the time in UTC/GMT.  Basically the sessions are at noon Illinois local time.

Comment: @BrettChampion are they weekly? Awesome if so!! This would be good to note, also! It is funny, because we usually use -s to denote multiple times, but it is actually not so obvious here, as both days have -s normally in their abbreviations. Maybe I'm just not using my skills of inference enough--as it does not denote a date, then it would be each week? Even still, "Every..." would make it distinctly evident! Excited for (this) Thursday's!

Comment: @CATrevillian They run weekly through late November, taking off August (for summer vacation) and the last week of October (Wolfram Technology Conference).  The ad links to the twitch.tv/wolfram/events which has the full schedule of presentations.

Answer (score 22):

[image: Network analysis and graph theory package for Mathematica]

Answer (score 21):

[image: Gimme paclets]

Answer (score 21):

[image: A Mathematica package for sharing images and code with StackExchange]

Answer (score 19):

[image: Mathematica palette to upload content to StackExchange easily]

Answer (score 15):

[image: PackageData.net: Mathematica Package Repository]

Answer (score 15):

[image: Join the Mathematica chat on StackExchange]

Answer (score 15):

[image: What are the most common pitfalls availing new users?]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Wolfram Language Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: I like the logo

Answer (score 13):

[image: Mathematica Programming: An Advanced Introduction]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Load the nets!]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Function repo]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Seamlessly call MATLAB from Mathematica]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Publication quality figure labels with LaTeX and Mathematica]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Animated Mathematica functions]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Use our data]

Answer (score 7):

[image: An elementary introduction to the Wolfram Language]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting